# How to access a smartcard in Java on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, pkcs#11

I'm trying to access a smartcard on a linux system on a VM. The USB device is mapped to the VM and can be listed via lsusb (ID 076b:3021 OmniKey AG CardMan 3121). I can access the smartcard via pkcs11-tool and pkcs15-tool. Also firefox can access the token via the /usr/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so library.

But when I try to access the smartcard from Java, an empty keystore is returned. I'm using the following configuration for the sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 provider.

```
name = PKCS11Test
library = /usr/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so
slot = 0
```

When using a different slot (I tried slot 0-15), I get CKR_PIN_INCORRECT errors or "PKCS11 not found". In my tests I'm loading the keystore like this:

```
char[] pin = "123456".toCharArray();
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", p);
ks.load(null, pin);
```

On the other hand the pkcs11-tool returned for slot 0:

`Slot 0           CCID Compatible

token model:   PKCS#15 emulated`

As Java seems to access the card on slot 0 (at least no error is returned), I'm probably doing something else wrong in accessing the keystore. How can I access the private key?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the solution.

Why ever, the slot 0 seems to be empty at all. Slot 1 and 2 have private keys, but were protected with different (local) PINs. With the netkey-tool I was able to set the local PIN to the global PIN. Afterwards accessing the card worked without a flaw.

Comment: You can set "plug_and_play = false" in the configuration file to disable the hotplug feature. Or don't rely on PKCS#11 slot indexes and search all slots instead (difficult sometimes..)

Comment: Thank you for the hint! With "configuration file" you mean the opensc.conf, do you? We moved to another smartcard which is not supported by opensc anymore. So I needed to find a new solution. Fortunately it's working at the moment.